# Problems with the Cat command

Tags: cat

I'm looking to number my paragraphs within a text file, I'm pretty sure I have to use the command `cat -n` or `cat -b` but I'm not sure how to use it, could someone expand upon this please.

Comment: `man cat` should help

Comment: `-b` and `-n` work on **lines**, you cannot use `cat`  to number paragraphs unless the consist off one line (in that case use `cat -b`). Do you have example input?

Comment: What is your question?  Are you trying to learn how to use the options of `cat`, or are you trying to solve a text-processing question and guessing that `cat` will be able to do it?  See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/271976) and [Pounding a Nail: Old Shoe or Glass Bottle?](http://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/408925)  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  You say that you want to number paragraphs, but you don’t define “paragraph”.  Computer parsing of free-form English text is a very hard problem — see [How to put sentences on separate lines in Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/190985/80216) — and you haven’t even specified that you’re dealing with English text.  (I don’t know that the problem would be much different in, say, French or German, but Arabic or Chinese would be different kettles of fish.)

Answer (score 1):

`cat -n file.txt`will display the content of the file.txt with line numbers.
If you want to have the line numbers in the file, then you can use an I/O redirect like
`cat -n file.txt > file1.txt`.
But i don't think there is an option to number paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

Grep can tell you how many empty lines there are in the file. That will usually be 1 less than the number of paragraphs. Unless there are extra blank lines in the text.

```
grep -c '^$' file.txt | wc -l
```

It can also tell you how many non blank lines there are. I would imagine if your paragraphs are all written continuously without new lines, this would work.

```
grep -cv '^$' a | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers indicate, `cat` isn't a very appropriate tool for this.

As I said in my comment, your question is ill-defined because you don’t specify how the command is supposed to recognize paragraphs.
One way to do that is by the first line being indented.
`nl -bp"^ "` is a command that’s fairly well suited to handling that form of input:

```
$ cat text1
Some Verse
 The quick brown fox
jumps over the lazy dog.
 The Owl and the Pussy-cat went to sea
In a beautiful pea green boat,

$ nl -bp"^ " text1
       Some Verse
     1   The quick brown fox
       jumps over the lazy dog.
     2   The Owl and the Pussy-cat went to sea
       In a beautiful pea green boat,
```

Another way is to use blank lines as separators.
`awk` is pretty good at handling that sort of thing.

```
$ cat num_pp
#!/bin/sh
awk 'BEGIN    {start=1}
     /^$/     {start=1}
    {
        if ($0 != ""  &&  start) {
                print ++ppnum, $0
                start=0
        } else print
    }' "$@"

$ cat text2
Some Verse
 The quick brown fox
jumps over the lazy dog.

The Owl and the Pussy-cat went to sea
 In a beautiful pea green boat,

$ ./num_pp text2
1 Some Verse
 The quick brown fox
jumps over the lazy dog.

2 The Owl and the Pussy-cat went to sea
 In a beautiful pea green boat,
```