# Convert the first letter of all "."-separated parts of a filename to uppercase except for the last one in Mac Bash

Tags: bash, text-processing, macos

I want to change the filename in the Mac Bash to initial capital after every dot/period, except for the filename extension.

- Input string example:

  ```
  one.two.three.four.txt
  ```
- Desired output:

  ```
  One.Two.Three.Four.txt
  ```

I tried the following:

```
echo 'one.two.three.four.txt' | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."} NF==1{$1=toupper($1)} {for (i=1;i<NF;i++) $i=toupper($i)} 1'
```

but this leads to the output:

```
ONE.TWO.THREE.FOUR.txt
```

So it's making everything uppercase (except for the extension).

I'm looking for initial Capital and extension in lower case.

Looking for a solution with `awk` as `sed \U` won't work (for me so far it's not) in Mac Bash.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is `bash` a requirement? Default shell on MacOS is `zsh` for a long time. There you can do `source="one.two.three";echo ${(C)source}` to `C`apitalize a parameter on expansion. In your case, you don't want `txt` to be capitalized, so do `${(C)source%txt}txt`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22046769/rename-files-mac-command-line

Comment: Also (loosely) related: [How to put sentences on separate lines …](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/190985/23408).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a variation of your attempt, the following should do:

```bash
echo "one.two.three.four.txt" |
     awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."} {for (i=1;i<NF;i++) {$i=toupper(substr($i,1,1)) substr($i,2)}}1'
```

This will again set the input and output field separator to the `.`.

It will then iterate over all fields but the last, and re-assamble each field to be the concatenation of upper-case version of the first character (using the `substr()` function to isolate it) and the remainder of the original content (again, using the `substr()` function).

In the end, it will print the current line including all modifications (this is the meaning of the seemingly "stray" `1` outside of the rule blocks).

---

**Addendum**: as noted in a comment, the OP actually wanted to not only ensure initial capitals, but full-fledged [capitalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitalization) of the `.`-separated parts, i.e. also forcing all subsequent letters to lower-case. This can be achieved by a minor modification of the above program:

```bash
echo "one.two.tHREE.four.txt" |
     awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."} {for (i=1;i<NF;i++) {$i=toupper(substr($i,1,1)) tolower(substr($i,2))}}1'
```

Comment: Your solution work perfect, if all are lower case, But if text is mixed case then initial capital not working  
`code

echo "one.TWO.THree.four.txt" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."} {for (i=1;i<NF;i++) {cap=toupper(substr($i,1,1)); sub(/^./,cap,$i)}}1'                                   

**boldOne.TWO.THree.Four.txt**
`

Comment: Need help in mixed case scenario to get 
`code Desired : One.Two.Three.Four.txt `

Comment: @IqbalSinghAulakh Well, that is a different problem then. Please be sure to provide this kind of details from the beginning, e.g. by including a complete set of input examples. In _this_ case, please edit your question to reflect this requirement - in general, however, please be aware that ["chameleon questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/630808) are seen critical, and that if you actually meant to ask something substantially different, you are expected to ask a _new_ question instead. Fortunately, it is comparatively easy to adapt the solution in this case.

Answer (score 4):

Another Perl solution is with a simple regular expression:

```
echo "one-one.two_two.three.four.txt"|perl -pe 's/([\w-]+\.)/ucfirst($1)/ge'
One-one.Two_two.Three.Four.txt
```

This looks repetitively (`\g`) for a group of word-characters with or without a `-` that are delimited by a dot character. The use of `\w` automatically implies that `_` is a valid character in that class. The first character of each group is then evaluated (`\e`) to lowercase.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with perl instead:

```
$ echo "one.two.three.four.txt" | 
    perl -F'\.' -lane 'print join ".", map{ucfirst}(@F);'
One.Two.Three.Four.Txt
```

To avoid also making the first letter of the extension upper case, you can skip the last `.`-separated element:

```
$ echo "one.two.three.four.txt" | 
    perl -F'\.' -lane 'print join( ".", map{ucfirst}(@F[0..$#F-1])) . ".$F[$#F]"'
One.Two.Three.Four.txt
```

Comment: Or slightly shorter `'$t=pop@F;print join(".",map{ucfirst}@F).".$t"'` (IMO also a little clearer, but that's subjective)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 ah yes, nice one!

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh`, using its `C`apitalisation parameter expansion flag (which converts the first character of each sequence of alnums to uppercase):

```
$ source=one.two.three.four.txt
$ print -r -- ${(C)source}
One.Two.Three.Four.Txt
```

Or doing only in the `r`oot name, leaving the `e`xtension alone:

```
$ print -r -- ${(C)source:r}.${source:e}
One.Two.Three.Four.txt
```

With GNU `sed` or `perl` using `\u` instead of `\U` to only capitalise the first character in the replacement (`\u`, `\U` are from `ex`/`vi` in the late 70s AFAIK, not supported by all `sed` implementations, but supported by `perl`):

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$source" | sed -E 's/[[:alnum:]]+/\u&/g'
One.Two.Three.Four.Txt
```

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$source" | perl -Mopen=locale -lpe 's/[[:alnum:]]+/\u$&/g'
One.Two.Three.Four.Txt
```

Or leaving the extension alone (here skipping the last sequence of alnums):

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$source" | sed -E 's/[[:alnum:]]+[^[:alnum:]]+/\u&/g'
One.Two.Three.Four.txt
```

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$source" | perl -Mopen=locale -lpe 's/[[:alnum:]]+[^[:alnum:]]+/\u$&/g'
One.Two.Three.Four.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Install GNU sed then:

```
$ echo 'one.two.three.four.txt' | sed -E 's/([^.])([^.]*\.)/\u\1\2/g'
One.Two.Three.Four.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ echo 'one.two.three.four.txt' | sed 's/\(.\)\([^.]*\.\)/\u\1\2/g'
One.Two.Three.Four.txt
```

Comment: Please keep in mind, though, that the OP stated "`sed \U` won't work" in the used Mac OS installation ...